# Pathologies that can lead to bleeding and cracked skin

Tags: dermatology

What skin condition or pathology might be depicted in the current image?

Suggestions would be helpful as they would allow more closer follow-up investigation at a local dermatologist.
[image]

Comment: We can't answer your question. We don't know your medical history nor your recent activities using your hands. A dermatologist doesn't need our help.